Downloading 1D OHLC data using thetadata
Program
Here's a simple Python program which uses the thetadata /hist/stock/ohlc endpoint to retrieve 1D candles for AAPL over a given date range.
import io
import time
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json"
}

interval   = 6 * 60 * 60 * 1000 # 6 hours

url = "http://127.0.0.1:25510/v2/hist/stock/ohlc"

params = {
    "start_date": "20240102",
    "end_date":   "20240130",
    "ivl":        interval,
    "root":       "AAPL",
    "use_csv":    "true"
}

start_time = time.time()
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
end_time = time.time()

elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
print(f"Request took {elapsed_time:.2f} seconds")

if response.status_code != 200:
    print("Error: ", response.status_code)
else:
    df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(response.content))

df



Output
The resulting dataframe:
>>> df
     ms_of_day     open      high       low    close    volume   count      date
0     34200000  190.940  191.8000  187.4700  188.070  41871539  605632  20240130
1     34200000  187.040  187.0950  184.7900  185.520  35049616  573009  20240131
2     34200000  183.985  186.8000  183.8200  186.660  36115114  588970  20240201
3     34200000  179.860  187.3300  179.2500  186.730  76910919  956323  20240202
4     34200000  188.150  189.2500  185.8400  188.350  49645818  710826  20240205
..         ...      ...       ...       ...      ...       ...     ...       ...
136   34200000  220.570  223.0300  219.7000  221.160  26834693  497239  20240814
137   34200000  224.600  225.3500  222.7600  225.060  27685884  506000  20240815
138   34200000  223.920  226.8271  223.6501  225.960  29280562  497581  20240816
139   34200000  225.720  225.7400  223.0400  224.930  25884935  532370  20240819
140   34200000  225.770  227.1700  225.4500  226.485  19963834  446631  20240820

Pulling all data
I'd like to retrieve the entire history of OHLC data for a given stock. Here I've changed the date range:
params = {
    "start_date": "19000101",
    "end_date":   "20250101",
    "ivl":        interval,
    "root":       "AAPL",
    "use_csv":    "true"
}

This does pull all the data from 2016 until present:
>>> df
      ms_of_day    open      high       low     close    volume   count      date
0      34200000  102.61  105.3680  102.0000  104.0501  54123788  309061  20160104
1      34200000  105.75  105.8500  102.4100  102.8044  45609925  278727  20160105
2      34200000  100.56  102.3700   99.8700  100.2460  58852334  360271  20160106
3      34200000   98.68  100.1300   96.6000   96.6000  63842150  392430  20160107
4      34200000   98.55   99.1100   96.7600   97.4500  57871838  362522  20160108
...         ...     ...       ...       ...       ...       ...     ...       ...
2169   34200000  220.57  223.0300  219.7000  221.1600  26834693  497239  20240814
2170   34200000  224.60  225.3500  222.7600  225.0600  27685884  506000  20240815
2171   34200000  223.92  226.8271  223.6501  225.9600  29280562  497581  20240816
2172   34200000  225.72  225.7400  223.0400  224.9300  25884935  532370  20240819
2173   34200000  225.77  227.1700  225.4500  226.4850  19963834  446631  20240820

However, it takes over 5 minutes to run:
Request took 351.61 seconds

yfinance
If I use yfinance to retrieve all AAPL data, it takes under 3 seconds:
import time
import yfinance_download

start_time = time.time()
result = yfinance_download.update_records(symbol='AAPL', interval='1d')
end_time = time.time()

elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
print(f"Request took {elapsed_time:.2f} seconds")

result

Output:
Request took 2.30 seconds
>>> result
                  Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close     Volume
Date
1980-12-12    0.128348    0.128906    0.128348    0.128348    0.098943  469033600
1980-12-15    0.122210    0.122210    0.121652    0.121652    0.093781  175884800
1980-12-16    0.113281    0.113281    0.112723    0.112723    0.086898  105728000
1980-12-17    0.115513    0.116071    0.115513    0.115513    0.089049   86441600
1980-12-18    0.118862    0.119420    0.118862    0.118862    0.091630   73449600
...                ...         ...         ...         ...         ...        ...
2024-08-14  220.570007  223.029999  219.699997  221.720001  221.720001   41960600
2024-08-15  224.600006  225.350006  222.759995  224.720001  224.720001   46414000
2024-08-16  223.919998  226.830002  223.649994  226.050003  226.050003   44340200
2024-08-19  225.720001  225.990005  223.039993  225.889999  225.889999   40687800
2024-08-20  225.770004  227.169998  225.449997  226.509995  226.509995   29914893

[11013 rows x 6 columns]

Question
Is there another approach for retrieving the data from thetadata that takes less time to complete?

Make concurrent requests.
We compute OHLC on the fly, this means that we read through every SIP trade for the symbol. This is often times millions of trades per day. There are plans to cache this data, so that it isn't as computationally intensive. SIP corrected OHLC bars is a relatively new data type with Theta Data. Any new data type we add has a probation phase where we test and determine the stability of it before spending resources caching this data for our full universe. The benefit of the on the fly computation is that you can request interval sizes on any time frame between 100ms and 1 hour. We have verified that this request is stable and its behavior is what we intended. All that is left is to cache this data, which we will get to in a few months.
Additionally, I would be surprised if yfinance is using SIP rules and has precision OHLC bars that also can found outside regular trading hours. If you are doing a one time download, what would it matter if it took a day to pull all of the symbols if it means the quality and flexibility of the data you're getting is superior?
Disclaimer: I'm the CEO of Theta Data.

yfinance is pretty great. But I'd recommend using OpenBB, which aims to be a FOSS alternative to the Bloomberg terminal. Here's their documentation: https://openbb.co/products/platform. It's as simple as:
from openbb import obb

obb.equity.price.historical('AAPL').to_df()

Here are some performance tests on my machine:
In [3]: %timeit obb.equity.price.historical('AAPL').to_dataframe()
979 ms ± 410 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [15]: %timeit yfinance.Ticker('AAPL').history(period='max')
364 ms ± 142 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [20]: %timeit obb.equity.price.historical('AAPL', provider='yfinance').to_dataframe()
202 ms ± 65.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

The actual fastest solution out of the ones I've tested is using OpenBB's SDK with the yfinance data connector.
OpenBB also has out-of-the-box support for yfinance (and every other option below) as a data connector.
Here are some additional freemium options:

Tiingo (https://www.tiingo.com/documentation/general/overview)
eodhd (https://eodhd.com/financial-apis/python-financial-libraries-and-code-samples)
Alpha Vantage (https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/)
Polygon (https://polygon.io/docs/stocks)


Great answer as well. Thank you!

Thanks! Can't have it any better than the CEO answering you though lol
